# Codeigniter Sessions Not working on specific computer

Tags: windows, codeigniter, session, cookies

My sessions work on all computers except 1 computer it does not work. It sets the session variable, but when you go back, the data doesn't exist in the session. I can test regular PHP cookies and those work, it's just Codeigniter, and 1 computer. I checked all the windows settings for cookies and they are all allowed.

What causes Codeigniter cookies not to work on just that 1 specific computer?
Thanks!

This is my test script:

```
if (isset($_GET['cookiecheck'])) {

    print_r($this->session->userdata);

} else {

    $cookie_data = array('valid' => true, 'name' => "My Name");

    $cookie_data = array('cookie' => $cookie_data);

    $this->session->set_userdata($cookie_data);

    die(header("Location: http://myurl/test?cookiecheck=1"));

}
```

Comment: What is your Codeigniter code about session? could post that code? did you try clearing cache on that computer and try again?

Comment: Yes I tried clearing the cache. Right now I'm using a simple test script to troubleshoot that I posted above.

Comment: did it give you any error message?

Comment: No error. It's sets the data. It can read it back right away. But when the page loads again the  data isn't there.

Comment: probably it cause from your browser settings not allow storing cookies or session, did you test different browser?

Comment: No I checked those. It stores regular PHP cookies. And I also switched to using the database and that didn't help.

Comment: Make sure you have set the session save path in config.php do not leave it null.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ensure your browser was not causing the problem, check your `phpinfo()`, to see if the session save path is defined, and your session expired time is define correctly, possibly double check your variables in `phpinfo()` against those in the working computer.